# ironMQ Push queue response

Tags: php, ironmq

I searched a lot but couldn't found any description on properties of responses that are being sent by REST API (http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#responses) Almost all properties of responses are self explanatory but some properties needs to be described. Let me mention some of them;

- In response of `GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue
  Name}/messages/{Message ID}/subscribers` request, what is property
  ID? (this is not message ID as I have checked it. In case of uni-cast
  push queue it is the same number as message_id+1)
- In response of `GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue
  Name}/messages/{Message ID}` request, what is property
  reserved_count?
- In response of `GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue Name}`
  request, what is property size? (It looks to be queue size from its
  value but again what is queue size? Queue Size on my Dashboard always
  displays zero)
- As per my understanding if a message is retrying 2nd or 3rd time its
  `retries_remaining` should be equal to `retries_total - number of
  retries attempts`. But this is not case. Every time I have seen that
  `retries_remaining` is not changing. What are the cases in which
  `retries_remaining` will change?
- After the message is tried `retries_total` number of times, message
  `status` should be changed to `error` but it remains `retrying`. why?
- Is there any log of message routing? means, if a message is first
  send to subscriber 1 but not received `200` in response. The same
  message will be then send to other subscriber say subscriber 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In response of `GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue
  Name}/messages/{Message ID}/subscribers` request, the property ID is the subscriber ID
- In response of `GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue
  Name}/messages/{Message ID}` request, the property `reserved_count` shows how many times the message have been reserved. After reservation if the timeout had been expired, the message would be placed back onto queue and the reserved_count would be increased.
- In `push queues` (in contrast to `pull queues`) the messages are not stored in the queue. That's why the size of any `push queue` is always zero.
- After the message is tried `retries_total` number of times the message status always changes to `error`. I think you had checked the status before the message was tried `retries_total` number of times. There is also the `retries_delay` between retries, default value is 60 seconds.
- Unfortunately now the routing log is not available, maybe in future will. You can use an `errorqueue`. It is the name of another queue where information about messages that can't be delivered after retrying retries number of times will be placed. For detailed information navigate to
  http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#error_queues